# specify host for application jar file

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes

I have created an HTTP server from the directory using this command:

```
python -c 'import BaseHTTPServer as bhs, SimpleHTTPServer as shs; bhs.HTTPServer(("0.0.0.0", 8089), shs.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler).serve_forever()'
```

I use Spark-K8s operator for the Spark application execution. As main file I want to use jar file stored in the directory (from which I create http server). However, I do not know to which host I should map my directory so it could be used by the Spark application running through the deployment.
When I run it with a current host I get this connection error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Basically, I have HTTP server which refers to specified host and port and I want to run this jar file using Spark on top of K8s. How can I define this host?

For now application definition looks like this:

```
apiVersion: sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: spark-example
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: Scala
  image: gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.0
  mainClass: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkExample
  mainApplicationFile: https://0.0.0.0:8089/spark_k8s_airflow.jar
  mode: cluster
  deps: {}
  driver:
    coreLimit: 1000m
    cores: 0.1
    labels:
      version: 2.4.0
    memory: 1024m
    serviceAccount: intended-mink-spark
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 1
    labels:
      version: 2.4.0
    memory: 1024m
  imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I have HTTP server which refers to specified host and port and I want to run this jar file using Spark on top of K8s. How can I define this host?

The kubernetes way of doing that is via a `Service`, which by default creates a DNS entry of the form `service-name.service-namespace.svc.cluster.local` where `service-name` and `service-namespace` are not those literal words, but the other 3 are literally that. However, if you just want to play around, and creating a `Service` is too much work, then you can use the current IP of the Pod in which your `SimpleHTTPServer` is running.

> `mainApplicationFile: https://0.0.0.0:8089/spark_k8s_airflow.jar`

Be aware that, at least as you have written the python example above, you cannot use `https:` since `SimpleHTTPServer` is just that **HTTP**. It's possible you can convince one of the built-in packages to serve https, but it'll be a lot more typing and arguably not worth the effort

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But what if I create SimpleHTTPServer from the shell script and not from Kubernetes?

Comment: I don't understand your question; I know it's a shell script, and just presumed it was running in-cluster -- but fine, even if it's not a Pod, surely it has an IP address. It will be trickier to do it _for real_ however, since you'll need either a headless Service or a legitimate DNS entry to plug into your yaml.